# CSS | Blur behind image

Tags: css

I use this loader spinner using css and jquery. I would like to blur the background exept the image from URL. Any idea ?

Css:

```
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background: url("http://enjoycss.com/bg-img/custom/107898-1py1ieu.1zm9.gif") 
center no-repeat #33333308;
}
```

Js

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
  });
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When the gif is showing you can add a `:before` pseudo-element to the body. The blurry effect can be tricky to achieve, I'd recommend using a blurry PNG or a svg as background, in the snippet below I'm just using color:

```
body:before{
  content:'';
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You can replace the body selector with a class and then with some jQuery remove or add the class to the body.

See this fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/3r1zc9gw/3/

Comment: Thx you for your interest.
Content:'', why for ? It makes my body blurred, but makes my app very slow. Also , body:before  still executed after loading...